# ImageField doesn't work when creating the ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

**models.py**

```
from PIL import Image
class Award_list(models.Model):
    award_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    award_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    award_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='award_pics',default='award.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.award_name} award'
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.award_image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.award_image.path)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Award'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from movies_list.models import Award_list

class Create_Award_list_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Award_list
        fields=['award_name','award_image']
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Award_list
from .forms import Create_Award_list_form

def Award_list_create(request):
    form=Create_Award_list_form(request.POST,request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # print(request.POST['award_name'])
        form.save()
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    context={
        "hell":'sanjeet',
        "form":form
    }   
    return render(request,'movies_list/award_list_create.html',context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/awards/new/',Award_list_create,name="award-list-create"),

]
```

**award_list_create.html**

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
               {{form.as_p}}
               {{hell}}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This all line of code work all fine with admin page and selecting image save into MEDIA_URL/awards_pics file but when i create a models based forms it select the default option even after selecting the image in .html  form.

Comment: What "default option"?

Comment: award_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='award_pics',default='award.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag so you can upload images from the html